# What happens in Node.JS if a Promise runs forever?

Tags: node.js, es6-promise

Let's say we have this buggy function:

```
async function buggy() {
  while(true) {
    await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1000));
  }
}
```

If you call it somewhere in NodeJS, would it permanently impact the server performances ?

If so, would it be better to always put a fail-safe mechanism like so for <strike>all</strike> untrusted promises:

```
new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  buggy().then(() => resolve);
  setTimeout(reject, 10000);
};
```

Comment: "*would it be better to always put a fail-safe mechanism like so for all promises*" I have never had a promise that doesn't resolve *except* if the code that produced it was bad. The way I avoid that is by testing. I don't really see much of a reason to put a bandaid on what is not going to be a problem most of the time and when it is, you're supposed to fix the source of the issue anyway.

Comment: Your suggestion is sort of equivalent of saying "Should we wrap each line of code in a `try/catch` just in case there is a problem?" to which the answer is the same - most lines of code won't throw errors. The ones that do, you want to fix anyway.

Comment: Frameworks like express have their timeouts already available, e.g https://github.com/expressjs/express/issues/3330

Comment: @VLAZ you make a good point, and I agree. But sometimes you **have** to call a function from an external library/package that you don't fully trust...

Comment: @Mageek then save the error handling for only those?

Comment: @WiktorZychla Great ! Thanks, I didn't know that. But would my `buggy` function actually "block a thread forever" ? or would it be practically inconsequential ? (this is more of a theoretical question for a deeper understanding of Node.JS)

Comment: @VLAZ Yes that's what I do, but I had never thought before of the possibility of a never-ending promise, which might be a good extra check to add in extreme cases ?

Comment: @Mageek "*would my buggy function actually "block a thread forever" ?*" no, it would not. It would run -> sleep for 1 second -> run -> sleep for 1 second -> etc. It will take up *some* CPU time but not a lot. And it will allow other stuff to run while it sleeps.

Comment: In the case the promise resolve state depend on external resource / timer that never end (Infinity as the timeout) that would work, otherwise the reject would never get called as the event loop is stuck

Comment: @RazLuvaton no, that's not true. `await` suspends the function.

Comment: The function yes but not the overall code

Comment: @RazLuvaton if the function is removed from the stack, *then it doesn't block the thread*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the case that the promise resolve state depends on an external resource / timer that never ends (Infinity as the duration) the suggested fail-safe would work and the server performance wouldn’t be affected so much.

```js
// this won’t stuck and the fail-safe will work
// (ignore the timer not being cleaned)
function buggy() {
   return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, Infinity));
}
```

Otherwise (in case the promise is solely synchronous, i.e. the resolve depends on an infinite loop that never ends) the reject function would never get called as the event loop is stuck which will stuck the server.

```js
// The fail-safe wouldn’t work and the server is stuck
async function buggy() {
  while(true);
}
```

**Edit:**
As pointed out by [@Vlaz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3689450/vlaz), in case the buggy function is similar to this:

```js
async function buggy() {
  while(true) {
    await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1000));
  }
}
```

The fail-safe would work and the server won’t stuck.

**Edit 2:**
In both cases you won't need a fail safe because if a the fail safe would work it means that the code doesn't stuck the Event Loop and also calling reject on the promise doesn't abort the buggy one

Comment: "*the reject function would never get called as the event loop is stuck which will stuck the server*" [No, that is not true](https://jsbin.com/rojofic/edit?js,console). [`await` suspends the function](https://jsbin.com/mesavil/1/edit?js,console) which allows it to not block further execution.

Comment: If you do `Promise.resolve().then(async () => {while(true);})` this will stuck the event loop

Comment: Correct. But that's not what OP's function does. It produces an unresolvable promise but it does not block the thread

Comment: I answered the specific case and the more general case, I edited my answer to add examples

Comment: Check my two examples that directly contradict your claim that the thread will be blocked.

Comment: Where are your examples?

Comment: [in my first comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68754128/what-happens-in-node-js-if-a-promise-runs-forever?noredirect=1#comment121508841_68754475)

Comment: I don’t think it’s contradict my answer, there are just an edge case

Comment: I agree with @RazLuvaton here, see [this exemple](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/IYZwngdgxgBAZgV2gFwJYHsIwEYIOZ5gAUAlDAN4BQMMA7gBaoA2ApkcgE4IskDclAX0qUomEMhgAHGAF4YEFrRgAFDugC2qEGyIcWIdEwBuLADQw9AKxZRkZGQD4K1HPkKkAdMnosIRUrJOegbGPPw02sgAKqjqLOgIyLos1rbmAIwADNmZfIJ5NIVFxSU0lJIeUMDIUPT+9k6iECEsHkzoeEQARFY2yF0kJJRAA)

Comment: You claimed that `reject` will never be called. The first example shows that it *is* called. You claimed that the event loop is stuck. The second link shows that not to be the case.

Comment: @Mageek ***that is different code***. Yes, different code behaves differently. I didn't think that needed to be mentioned.

Comment: @Mageek but not the code in your question. Which the answer *initially* said will block the thread. When I showed actual examples it doesn't, then Raz added irrelevant code that behaves differently to convince me otherwise.

Comment: @VLAZ Raz said in his initial comment "if it depends on a timer, the fail-safe works, **otherwise** (which I understood as: if it depends on internal calculations like a while loop) it won't work". Anyway, let's not argue on semantics, I believe all of us understood each others now.

Comment: I added a clarification to the otherwise (when is solely depend on sync operations).

Comment: @Mageek, you can accept the answer if you agree with me 

Comment: @Vlaz, what do you think about the answer now after the edit? (Look at the otherwise section too)

Comment: @Mageek semantics are *hugely* important. If you have an async function that blocks the thread that's *very* different to an unresolvable promise. If you want to protect from busy loops that block execution that's completely not what you showed in your question. Furthermore, while unresolvable promises are rare, calling a library that blocks execution is going to be in the *very extreme minority*. No implementation I know of uses a busy loop to delay a promise resolution.

Comment: @VLAZ Semantics are important, but the intent is also important. Humans can't always communicate in a semantically perfect manner, if only because words rarely have a single definition. The intent of my question was about code that "runs forever" (which could mean blocking execution, or could mean never-resolved promise, I wasn't even sure about what I was asking in the first place, if I were, I would probably already have the answer). Both your and Raz's contribution were helpful to me. I think there is value in answering tangentially to a question, and also in being semantically precise.

Answer (score 2):

No, there is nothing wrong with your `buggy` function. To say that a promise *runs* is misleading: a promise doesn't run. It is an object that has provided a callback. As long as that callback `resolve` isn't called, and its `then` method isn't called, there is nothing happening with that promise object.

The following happens when `buggy` is run:

- `new Promise` creates a promise object
- `setTimeout` is run and completes immediately. It registers the `resolve` callback.
- `await` is executed, which actually calls `then` on the above promise to add a listener, and makes `buggy` return. If this is the first time, then it returns a pending promise to the caller.
- One second later (during which there is no activity related to `buggy`), the `setTimeout` API will put the `resolve` callback on the relevant job queue.
- When the event loop checks this queue, it consumes and executes this job. The promise API (that provided the `resolve` callback) puts the promise in a resolved state and puts a notification for its then-listeners (including the one created by `await`) as a job on the promise job queue.
- When the event loop checks this queue, it consumes and executes the listener(s). This restores the execution context of `buggy`, which then continues with its loop.
- Repeat these steps from the top

The impact on the engine or memory is comparable with a `setInterval` call that you never clear with `clearInterval`. There is just a little bit more overhead due to the extra promise related jobs (in addition to the regular timer job) that kick in after each second, and the saved execution state of  `buggy`, which is comparable with what you would have with an infinite generator (using `yield`).

Comment: I think the buggy function is just an example, it’s more of a black box

Comment: @RazLuvaton Yes exactly, that's what I had in mind. But @trincot's detailed explanation of `buggy` is very helpful.